# BigQuery: two hitlevel custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I can't seem to get a query that gives me all sessions in which customdimensionX has value X and customdimensionY has value Y within the same hit. The query I currently have results in no results found.

Can anybody help me on this:)?
Thanks!

```
SELECT  sum(totals.visits)

from TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxxx.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-3-1'),TIMESTAMP('2016-3-1'))

WHERE 
  (hits.customDimensions.index=x AND hits.customDimensions.value='x') 
  AND (hits.customDimensions.index=y AND hits.customDimensions.value='y')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit strange to answer my own question but it might be useful for someone else:) I got to the right number in the following way:

```
SELECT EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(uniqueVisitId) as sessions
FROM( 
 SELECT
   CONCAT(fullvisitorid,"_",string(visitId)) AS uniqueVisitId,
   MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index=x,hits.customDimensions.value,NULL)) WITHIN hits AS x,
   MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index=y,hits.customDimensions.value,NULL)) WITHIN hits AS y,
   hits.hitNumber

   FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxxxxx.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-3-1'),TIMESTAMP('2016-3-1'))

   having
    (x contains 'x' and y contains 'y')
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below options (don't have chance to test, but  should be close to what you need, if not exactly):

```
SELECT SUM(totals.visits) 
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([66080915.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-3-1'),TIMESTAMP('2016-3-1'))
OMIT RECORD IF 
SUM((hits.customDimensions.index=x AND hits.customDimensions.value='x')
 OR (hits.customDimensions.index=y AND hits.customDimensions.value='y')
) != 2 

SELECT SUM(totals.visits) FROM (  
  SELECT totals.visits, 
  SUM((hits.customDimensions.index=x AND hits.customDimensions.value='x')
   OR (hits.customDimensions.index=y AND hits.customDimensions.value='y')
  ) WITHIN RECORD AS check,
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([66080915.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-3-1'),TIMESTAMP('2016-3-1'))
  HAVING check = 2  
)
```

> ADDED

If customDimensions where groupped by specific hits like hits.hit.customVariables - you would be able to identify both conditions within the same hit by using
`WITHIN hits.hit` or `OMIT hits.hit IF`
 vs. respectively
`WITHIN RECORD` or `OMIT RECORD IF`

But I've checked [BigQuery Export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719) and it seems not a case.
I dont see way to distinguish dimensions per specific hit.
Custom Dimensions are presented by level - user/session level, product level and hits level.
Only product level custom dimentions can be identifyed/queryed per product.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the thing is that both the condition for customdimension x and y should be met within the same hit, i think your suggestion selects sessions in which both conditions are met somewhere in the session and not specifically in the same hit?

Comment: :o) I was focused on fixing your WHERE clause, assuming this was your showstopper. the rest of your code i havent touched

Comment: allright, well thanks anyway @Mikhail Berlyant . I found another way to get my results (see below), might not be the cleanest, if there is a better way please let me know.

Comment: Glad you got it. I feel my answer helped you to get to this point - especially with using WHITHIN (and this was exactly my focus). If so you can at least mark it as useful by voting up on it.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I have a question related use custom dimension to get new user count and user count. here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016315/google-big-query-using-custom-dimension-to-get-new-user-count-and-user-count/48030060?noredirect=1#comment83106118_48030060 can you please take a look if you have time? Thanks