# Google Big Query using Custom Dimension to get new user count and user count

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to get the new user and user count, qualified visitors by custom dimension value and date. Here is the code. But I couldn't get the data tie with Google Analytics. I think the problem is the UNNEST creates duplicate and total.newVisits is on different granularity. Thank you!

```
SELECT
      PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', t.date) as Date
      ,count(distinct(FullvisitorID)) as visitor_count
      ,sum( totals.newVisits ) AS New_Visitors
      ,if(customDimensions.index=2, customDimensions.value,null)  as orig
    FROM `table` as t
      CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit
      CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) AS customDimensions
    WHERE
      date='20170101'

GROUP BY DATE,if(customDimensions.index=2, customDimensions.value,null)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) AS Date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullvisitorid) visitor_count,
  SUM(totals.newVisits) AS New_Visitors,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index = 2 LIMIT 1) orig
FROM `dataset_id.ga_sessions_20170101`
GROUP BY Date, orig
```

It's basically the same thing but instead of doing the `UNNEST` in the outer query this solution only applies this operation at the `hit` level which avoids the duplication of `totals.newVisits` you observed in your query.

Comment: Hi Willian, Thank you for the help. However, I think the new visitor account and visitor count are still duplicating. I checked the result by using the query, the number is still really larger than GA. I attached the GA interface that I used. Thank you!!!

Comment: hmm that's weird. As for the query I suggested there's no place where the duplication could be happening. Maybe you could run some sanity checks in your GA report to see if it's being built as expected. As the `visitor_count` is a distinct count it can't be duplicated for instance (no matter how many duplicates it happen end result is the same)

Comment: Is it possible that a user visit has multiple customer dimension.index-2 value ? so when it does the summing, a user is counted multiple times but for different values?